# List Detect Position of Equal Sequence

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I find the position of the first element (here 5) of the last equal sequence (here 5,5,5) ?

```
list = {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5}
```

In this case: 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = With[{s = Split @ #}, 
  1 + Length @ Flatten @ Drop[s, -(1 + LengthWhile[Reverse@s, Length @ # == 1 &])]] &;
f @ list
```

> 8

```
f @ {7, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9}
```

> 6

Comment: Thank you !! Would you mind to explain this part : `Length @ # > 1 &][[-1, 1]]]`. I am not familiar with this style of programming.

Comment: `First@Position[list, 5]`

Comment: @james, i updated with new method. The older one with `Select` was not general enough.

Comment: This is great work !! Thank you very much !  If you have the time, can you just quickly describe in your answer how your method works ? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: @james, the following are intemediate steps : For  `lst = {7, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9}`,  (1) `s = Split[lst]` splits list into parts with same elements, (2) ` LengthWhile[Reverse@s, Length @ # == 1 &]` gives the number of  singleton elements at the end of `s`. The part we want is the last part that remains after we drop the singleton elements at the end of `s` (call it `p`). The number of `lst` elements that precede `p` is the sum of the parts in `s` that precede `p` in `s`. ...

Comment: ... So when we drop `1+LengthWhile[Reverse@s, Length @ # == 1 &]`  parts from the end of `s` and `Flatten` the result we end up with elements of `lst` that come before `p`; we add 1 to the length of these elements to find the position of the first element of `p` in `lst`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`SequencePosition` is made-to-order for this task, identifying the positions of the first and last element of a designated sequence.  And, `Repeated[z_, {2, Infinity}]` designates any sequence of repeated characters of length two or greater.

```
g[ll_] := Length@ll + 1 - 
    SequencePosition[Reverse@ll, {Repeated[z_, {2, Infinity}]}][[1, 2]]

g@{2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5}
(* 8 *)

g@{7, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9}
(* 6 *)
```

Alternatively, and a bit more briefly,

```
h[ll_] := SequencePosition[ll, {Repeated[z_, {2, Infinity}]}, Overlaps -> False][[-1,1]]
```

which gives the same results.